# Descendants in C# do not give the right value

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am very new in XML using C# i have a XML i need to go through specific children in the parent 
i need to get the id and the call variables variables i did this but every time did not go through the loop

Do i need to go through all of the parent of xml until i got the tree that i want ??

the xml

```
<message xmlns="jabber:client" to="1072@finesse1.dcloud.cisco.com" id="/finesse/api/User/1072/Dialogs__1072@finesse1.dcloud.cisco.com__104Y2" from="pubsub.finesse1.dcloud.cisco.com">
<event xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#event">
 <items node="/finesse/api/User/1072/Dialogs">
  <item id="460c2d27-c914-4c24-a95f-edf9f8df45c21535">
    <notification xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub">
      <Update>
        <data>
          <dialogs>
            <Dialog>
              <associatedDialogUri></associatedDialogUri>
              <fromAddress>1071</fromAddress>
              <id>18639330</id>
              <mediaProperties>
                <DNIS>1072</DNIS>
                <callType>AGENT_INSIDE</callType>
                <dialedNumber>1072</dialedNumber>
                <outboundClassification></outboundClassification>
                <callvariables>
                  <CallVariable>
                    <name>callVariable1</name>
                    <value></value>
                  </CallVariable>
                  <CallVariable>
                    <name>callVariable2</name>
                    <value></value>
                  </CallVariable>
                  <CallVariable>
                    <name>callVariable3</name>
                    <value></value>
                  </CallVariable>
                  <CallVariable>
                    <name>callVariable4</name>
                    <value></value>
                  </CallVariable>
                  <CallVariable>
                    <name>callVariable5</name>
                    <value></value>
                  </CallVariable>
                  <CallVariable>
                    <name>callVariable6</name>
                    <value></value>
                  </CallVariable>
                  <CallVariable>
                    <name>callVariable7</name>
                    <value></value>
                  </CallVariable>
                  <CallVariable>
                    <name>callVariable8</name>
                    <value></value>
                  </CallVariable>
                  <CallVariable>
                    <name>callVariable9</name>
                    <value></value>
                  </CallVariable>
                  <CallVariable>
                    <name>callVariable10</name>
                    <value></value>
                  </CallVariable>
                </callvariables>
              </mediaProperties>
              <mediaType>Voice</mediaType>
              <participants>
                <Participant>
                  <actions>
                    <action>ANSWER</action>
                  </actions>
                  <mediaAddress>1072</mediaAddress>
                  <mediaAddressType>AGENT_DEVICE</mediaAddressType>
                  <startTime>2017-09-15T19:23:36.872Z</startTime>
                  <state>ALERTING</state>
                  <stateCause></stateCause>
                  <stateChangeTime>2017-09-15T19:23:36.872Z</stateChangeTime>
                </Participant>
                <Participant>
                  <actions>
                    <action>UPDATE_CALL_DATA</action>
                    <action>DROP</action>
                  </actions>
                  <mediaAddress>1071</mediaAddress>
                  <mediaAddressType>AGENT_DEVICE</mediaAddressType>
                  <startTime>2017-09-15T19:23:36.609Z</startTime>
                  <state>INITIATED</state>
                  <stateCause></stateCause>
                  <stateChangeTime>2017-09-15T19:23:36.819Z</stateChangeTime>
                </Participant>
              </participants>
              <state>ALERTING</state>
              <toAddress>1072</toAddress>
              <uri>/finesse/api/Dialog/18639330</uri>
            </Dialog>
          </dialogs>
        </data>
        <event>POST</event>
        <requestId></requestId>
        <source>/finesse/api/User/1072/Dialogs</source>
      </Update>
    </notification>
  </item>
 </items>
</event>
</message>
```

that is the 
Code

```
XElement xmlroots = XElement.Parse(parsingNewXML);
//Dialog = xmlroots.Element("Dialog").Value;
var CallVariable = parsingNewXML.Contains("CallVariable");
var startCall = parsingNewXML.Contains("ALERTING");

if (CallVariable == true && startCall == true)
{

    foreach (XElement callID in xmlroots.Descendants("Dialog"))
    {
        DialogID = callID.Element("id").Value;
        //System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(DialogID);
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
        DispatcherPriority.Background,
        new Action(() => ((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).answerCall.Visibility = Visibility.Visible));
    }
    foreach (XElement callVariables in xmlroots.Descendants("CallVariables"))
    {
        foreach (XElement callVariable in xmlroots.Descendants("CallVariable"))
        {
            list = callVariable.Element("value").Value;
        }
    }
   // state = second.Element("state").Value;
}
```

Comment: Your code and the xml aren't consistent.  I can't tell what you need.  The "if" clause doesn't make any sense.  No idea what parsingmsg refers to.  It is much easier to use descendants instead of ancestors.

Comment: @jdweng
please help me i want to get the id from this xml what should i do i do not know what is the code to write to get the id i tried this code but did not help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first problem is that you're just calling `Descendants("Dialog")`, `Descendants("CallVariables")` etc. Those look for elements in the global namespace - but all the elements you're looking for are *actually* in a namespace of `http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub` due to this:

```
<notification xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub">
```

When you see `xmlns="..."` that sets the default namespace for all descendants. That default can be explicitly overridden by element names that specify a namespace - or it can be changed by another descendant with `xmlns=...`. (Your document contains multiple levels of defaults.)

Fortunately, LINQ to XML makes it easy to specify namespaces, due to the implicit conversion from `string` to `XNamespace`, and the `XName +(XNamespace, string)` operator:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(...);
XNamespace pubsub = "http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub";
// Find all the descendants with a local name of "Dialog" in the
// namespace specified by the pubsub variable
foreach (XElement dialog in doc.Descendants(pubsub + "Dialog"))
{
    ...
}
```

As a second issue, look at this second loop:

```
foreach (XElement callVariables in xmlroots.Descendants("CallVariables"))
{
    foreach (XElement callVariable in xmlroots.Descendants("CallVariable"))
    {
        list = callVariable.Element("value").Value;
    }
}
```

There are three problems with this:

- There are no elements in your document called `CallVariables` - there's `callvariables` instead. XML is case-sensitive.
- I'm sure you don't want the combination of *every* call variable in *every* call variables element. Instead, I'd expect something like:

  ```
  foreach (var callVariables in doc.Descendants(pubsub + "callvariables"))
  {
      // Note use of Elements, not Descendants. You still need
      // the namespace part though...
      foreach (var callVariable in callVariables.Elements(pubsub + "CallVariable"))
      {
          // Do what you want
      }
  }
  ```
- Currently you're just replacing the `list` variable in the body of the loop, which means only the last iteration of the loop is actually useful.

There may well be many other things wrong with the code - it seems odd to parse the XML and then check whether the *string* representation contains a particular string (rather than checking for the existence of a particular element, for example) but those should get you started.

Comment: thanks for your answer that what i was searching about , I did not know about  namespace thanks alot for the explanation also 

Please could you tell me why there is someone give me -ve in the question to improve myself next time

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you really want but this extracts the id's and the callvariables to a list of dialog object. If you want to use ling-to-xml you need to parse an XDocument first, then loop through the desired descendants. Finally just get the values from the callvariables with another loop.

Don't forget, to care about the exception at the end.

```
        public class Dialog
        {
            public int id;
            public List<CallVariable> callVariables = new List<CallVariable>();
            public struct CallVariable
            {
                public string name;
                public string value;
            }

        }

        public List<Dialog> GetDialogsFromXml(string xml)
        {
            try
            {
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
                List<Dialog> dialogs = new List<Dialog>();

                foreach (XElement item in doc.Root.Descendants("{http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub}Dialog"))
                {

                    int dialogid = int.Parse(item.Element("{http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub}id").Value);

                    List<Dialog.CallVariable> callvariables = new List<Dialog.CallVariable>();

                    foreach (XElement callVariableNode in item.Descendants("{http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub}callvariables").FirstOrDefault().Descendants("{http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub}CallVariable"))
                    {
                        callvariables.Add(new Dialog.CallVariable() { name=callVariableNode.Element("{http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub}name").Value, value = callVariableNode.Element("{http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub}value").Value });
                    }

                    dialogs.Add(new Dialog() { id = dialogid, callVariables = callvariables });

                }
                return dialogs;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //handle if something goes wrong
                return null;

            }

        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use xml linq.  You also need to use the namespace to get the elements.  You can avoid the namespace by getting the LocalName like I did for dialogs. :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement dialogs = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "dialogs").FirstOrDefault();
            XNamespace ns = dialogs.GetDefaultNamespace();

            var results = dialogs.Elements(ns + "Dialog").Select(x => new {
                id = (int)x.Element(ns + "id"), 
                associatedDialogUri = (string)x.Element(ns + "associatedDialogUri"),
                fromAddress = (string)x.Element(ns + "fromAddress"),
                dnis = (int)x.Descendants(ns + "DNIS").FirstOrDefault(),
                callType = (string)x.Descendants(ns + "callType").FirstOrDefault(),
                dialedNumber = (int)x.Descendants(ns + "dialedNumber").FirstOrDefault(),
                outboundClassification = (string)x.Descendants(ns + "outboundClassification").FirstOrDefault(),
                callVariables = x.Descendants(ns + "CallVariable").Select(y => new {
                    name = (string)y.Element(ns + "name"),
                    value = (string)y.Element(ns + "value")
                }).ToList(),
                participants = x.Descendants(ns + "Participant").Select(y => new
                {
                    actions = y.Descendants(ns + "action").Select(z => (string)z).ToList(),
                    namemediaAddress = (int)y.Element(ns + "mediaAddress"),
                    mediaAddressType = (string)y.Element(ns + "mediaAddressType"),
                    startTime = (DateTime)y.Element(ns + "startTime"),
                    state = (string)y.Element(ns + "state"),
                    stateCause = (string)y.Element(ns + "stateCause"),
                    stateChangeTime = (DateTime)y.Element(ns + "stateChangeTime")
                }).ToList(),
                state = (string)x.Descendants(ns + "state").FirstOrDefault(),
                toAddress = (int)x.Descendants(ns + "toAddress").FirstOrDefault(),
                uri = (string)x.Descendants(ns + "uri").FirstOrDefault()

            }).ToList();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just code without any explanation isn't nearly as helpful as a thorough explanation of what changes you've made and why.

Comment: A picture is worth a 1000 words.  Having code with good variables names, easy to read, and well organized is better than 1,000,000,000 words.  Now did you have to count the number of zeroes to know the number was a billion or should I have use Billion instead of the digits 0 & 1.  Do you think my code needs comments?  What comments?  It is better to document the code then write explanation.  Picking good variable names can eliminate the need for comments.

Comment: I didn't ask for comments. I asked for explanation. You haven't given *any* explanation for why you need to worry about a namespace, for example, which is the most important aspect. (I also take issue with your approach to *taking* the first namespace - what if the doc later contains other `dialogs` elements in different namespaces?)

Comment: (I'd also argue that variable names of `x` and `y` aren't nearly as clear as `dialog` and `participant` or `variable` would be.)

Comment: I agree that x & y aren't clear names, but in this case the element names are next to x & y.  If you look at the posting making x and y variable names would make some of the code move off view so you would need to use the scroll bar.  My computer science teacher always graded on white space on both left and right side of print out.  Using long variable names got lower grades, using short variable names got lower grades.  Size had to be just right.

Comment: "but in this case the element names are next to x & y" - well all I can say is that *I* (trying to read your code) had to look for quite a while to see what they meant each time. It isn't obvious at a glance. If you think your answer is fine as it is, then sure, leave it as it is. I think it would be **much** more helpful with an explanation of what the OP is doing wrong in their original code, and I'd argue that I have reasonable experience of what makes for a helpful answer.

Comment: I don't think the names of the selectors x, y, z add or subtract to the understanding of the code.  To use names would be like replacing +,-,*,/ with add, subtract multiply,divide.  It would actually make the code harder to read.

Comment: No, because + and add are synonyms, whereas x provides no context, and dialog does. You haven't tried to read your code as someone who doesn't already know what it's trying to do - I have, and found it hard to read. You can ignore the feedback if you want of course, but it's feedback that comes from experience of finding the code harder to read than it needs to be.

Comment: I usually try to use very descriptive name for variables include FOR LOOP index.  but when it comes to writing a Bubble Sort I can never find anything better then i & j.